# how can i make the same style dropdown menu

Tags: flutter

[image]

How can i make this dropdown style in flutter,
also the CupertinoSwitch color change like this one ---background color white & Button color Amber.

Thanks

Comment: please share some code

Comment: I dont know how to make this style , I have done only Listtile.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use an [AnimatedContainer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html) in combination with the [expandable](https://pub.dev/packages/expandable) package to achieve most of the UI for this widget.

As for the Cupertino switch, you have a property in the widget itself to set a color when the button is active:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSwitch/activeColor.html